# How to check if file transfer is done to hdfs completed or not

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am copying file to HDFS from other script. I cannot know if file transfer done since other system is doing the file transfer to HDFS. I want to perform next operation as soon as file copy done. How to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

As and when you have a chain of commands, it is best advised to develop a pipeline which also allows plugging any error handling routines or alerting routines if need be.

Have you tried Apache Oozie/Airflow or tools in the similar ecosystem?

Using such a toolset, you can then define the first task as copy and then followed by any other task in line.

Comment: This file transfer will happen from another system which I don't have any access. I just give request for file transfer to my hdfs. I won't know when they will start transfer or complete. So i have to just poll the hdfs whether file came in some time intervals.

Comment: Interesting, how will the remote host even write to this cluster? You will have to write the file on local (or a host of machines running your cluster) and then copy the file to HDFS. You can create an Oozie polling job to watch a particular directory and then trigger file copy.